# Using Latex in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, latex

I want to write a program that allows me to type in plain text and LaTex code into a text field and displays in real time that text parsed with LaTex, essentially how the preview panel works in stackexchange. For example, as I'm typing this, $this code$ would be displayed in typeset format (if I was on mathexchange) in real type as I'd be typing this message. Is there a libarary I can use for C++ that would let me write a program like that? Where should I begin? Thanks for your time! (Oh, I also plan on developing this through QT).

Comment: You mean, just like [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)?

Comment: You mean like texstudio?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814825/how-to-create-parser-for-tex